# Saving file in phone storage with IBM Worklight

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to achieve the following functionality with Worklight:

I have a JS variable that has the value of a very long string.
I need to create a file that contains the value of the variable and save the file to the user's phone device.

Is there any file handling functionality in Worklight that allows the saving of files in the device's storage?

Comment: Worklight is not meant for this; you can use the Cordova File API to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worklight is not giving any API to achieve file saving and retrieving functionality. However you can use cordova plugin's to achieve the same. please find below code for your need.

```
//It will fetch the sample.txt if already available else it will create a new file named sample.txt
    fileSystem.root.getFile("sample.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotEntryForFile, fail);

    function gotEntryForFile(entry) {
        entry.createWriter(gotWriterForFile, fail);
    }

    function gotWriterForFile(writer) {
        // move  the cursor to end of the file
        writer.seek(writer.length);
        // Write the vaules of your varibale 
        writer.write(varibaleForFileUse);
    }

// To read the text from file
 function gotReaderForFile(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("read success");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    // To read the file as text
    reader.readAsText(file);
};
```

Note the following while using this plugin.

- First you have to enable permissions for file operations. For iOS edit the Cordova.plist
- It will support only iOS, Android , Windows Phone 7 , BlackBerry WebWorks ( > OS 5.0)
- For iOS encoding parameter is not supported, UTF8 encoding is always used.
- writer always write from beginning of the file. better use seek first to go to EOF
- If you are using iOS you can set the meta data by `setMetadata`. It is not supported by other os's

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Cordova File plugin and use the [FileWriter object](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter) to write the file and [FileReader](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader) to read it.

Comment: You do not need to install it, it is already there (for example in Android check the config.xml). You just call the API.